# converting from dfa to regular expression

Tags: regex, dfa

Can someone explain to me how to convert this DFA to a regular expression?

I have tried using Arden’s theorem but I don’t know how to simplify the equations to get the regular expression for this DFA. If someone could show me how to simplify the expressions, that would be a great help.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's name the states  ...  as follows:

[image]

These states represent the expressions that lead to that state when starting from starting state  so the solution we look for is <sub><sub>end</sub></sub> =  +

Then create the equations for each of the states in terms of the other states:

= ε
       = ( + )1
       = 2
       = ( +  + )(3 + 4)
       = ( + )5
       = (6 + 7)
      <sub><sub>end</sub></sub> =  +

We can substitute ,  and :

= (ε + 2)1 = 1 + 21
       = (ε + 2 + )(3 + 4) = (ε + 2)(3 + 4) + (3 + 4)
       = ( + )5(6 + 7) = 5(6 + 7) + 5(6 + 7)
      <sub><sub>end</sub></sub> =  +

We can apply Arden’s theorem to each of these:

= 1(21)*
       = (ε + 2)(3 + 4)(3 + 4)*
       = (56 + 57)(5(6 + 7))*
      <sub><sub>end</sub></sub> =  +

We can substitute :

= (ε + 1(21)*2)(3 + 4)(3 + 4)* = (12)*(3 + 4)(3 + 4)* 
       = 5(6 + 7)(5(6 + 7))*
      <sub><sub>end</sub></sub> =  +

and  and  :

= (12)*(3 + 4)(3 + 4)*
       = (12)*(3 + 4)(3 + 4)*5(6 + 7)(5(6 + 7))*

And the solution:

<sub><sub>end</sub></sub> = (12)*(3 + 4)(3 + 4)*(ε + 5(6 + 7)(5(6 + 7))*)
              = (12)*(3 + 4)(3 + 4)*(5(6 + 7))*

---

NB: if we write this as a regex as used in programming, then <sub><sub>end</sub></sub> can be written as:

```
^(12)*[34]+(5[67])*$
```